# Search value in another SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables: `tblPayroll` and `tblKPI`.
`tblPayroll` is the list of all the payrolls and `tblKPI` is the list of payrolls that users have entered into the database.
Both have a column named `Payroll`.
I want to conjure a list of the Payrolls that are not entered in `tblKPI` by the users.

I don't know `JOINS` which is why I don't know where to start.

Comment: Please add the table schema and query which you are using.

Comment: What SQL engine are You using? Could You please give us information if You tried anything so far?

Comment: You could look into `Joins` or use a `Not In`/`Not Exists` depending on your engine

Comment: You are working on mysql or sql server ?

Comment: I am working on SQL Server

Comment: @Lawakuch Kurmi - What is schema ??? :(

Comment: Are tblPayroll and tblKPI having same columns ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you are going to work with SQL you really should learn at least the basics, and joins are a basic part of the language.
I will show you an example that selects all records from `tblPayroll` that does not have a matching `Payroll` in `tblKPI`, but you know what they say - 
give a man a fish and he will eat for a day. Teach him how to fish and we will sit around in a bout drinking beer all day...

```
SELECT *
FROM tblPayroll p
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM tblKPI k
    WHERE k.Payroll = p.Payroll
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the resolution Zohar. I appreciate your intent to motivate me go further and I will keep this in mind. why do we have a varaible p and k ???

Comment: They are not variables but table aliases. they enable you to refer to the table using it's alias thus shorten the sql statement and making it more readable. BTW, if an answer solved your problem you should mark it as accepted so that other people will know that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need joins for this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Payrolls 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM tblKPI
                    WHERE tblKPI.Payroll = Payrolls.Payroll)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `LEFT JOIN` and check for `NULL`:

```
SELECT p.* FROM tblPayroll p
LEFT JOIN tblKPI k ON p.Payroll = k.Payroll
WHERE k.Payroll IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

SELECT *
FROM tblPayroll 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM tblKPI

)